# Why are AFTER triggers not supported for views?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Can any one explain in detail with an example if possible, why `AFTER` triggers are not supported for views in SQL Server?

I know we use `AFTER` triggers after `insert`, `update` or `delete` on a table, then why not on a view, too?

Comment: You want an example of something that's not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is only possible to do something `instead of` an DDL statement on a view.

Views themselves don't contain data, so it is not possible to do something before or after a change since it can't be sure how one change on the view affects the data below it.

Example:

If you have a view resulting in one row, and you update that row, that row might disappear, 'another' row might pop up, and there is no way to tell the relation between the first and the last.